# Error with React Native when trying to start App

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

I'm following the steps provided in the [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to set up the environment for React Native.
I have installed `create-react-native-app` as well as `expo-cli` .
Further I have created an app using `expo init`.

Now when I'm trying to run the app with `yarn start` or `npm start` I get the following error:

```
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How do i solve it? is that something related to powershell? (But i get it in Command Prompt too)

P.S. I'm using Windows 8, Expo 3.24.2, yarn 1.22.4, node 10.15.3

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750620/how-to-fix-error-spawnsync-powershell-exe-enoent could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same error while running yarn start.
To fix this: go to

1. Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings ->
   Environment Variables.
2. Under User variables -> Variable PATH -> add a new path i.e,
   (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0)
3. Then click Ok and close the Control Panel.
4. Now open Windows Powersell and write:
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
5. Click enter and close the powershell
6. reopen the cmd and type yarn start or npm start

Error is gone :)