# Execute Load Runner test integration in Azure pipeline unable to read test scenario file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am integrating load runner in azure pipeline using load runner plugin in i have created pipeline as follows

trigger:

- none

pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: ExecuteLoadRunnerProfessional@0
  inputs:
  ControllerUrl: 'http://serverURL:port'
  UserName: 'username'
  Password: 'Password'
  Domain: ''
  Project: 'Projectname'
  TestId: 'testid'
  TestInstance: 'Instance name'
  TimeslotDuration: '60'

  PostRunAction: 'Collate and Analyze'
  ReportName: 'loadtest_Report'
  ReportType: 'HTML'
  ReportPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\res'
  FailTaskOnErrors: true
  FailTaskOnSLA: true
  IgnoreSSL: true
  displayName: 'Run LoadRunner Enterprise Test'

I am getting following log - There are no scenario found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gv6u.png)

I have tried command line approach as well getting same log error

I am looking for the solution on the above question. I want to execute scenario file from the controller using azure pipeline

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline task `ExecuteLoadRunnerProfessional@0` comes from the extension [LoadRunner Professional Tests Automation - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Micro-Focus.LoadRunnerProfessionalTestsAutomation), whose introduction states that

> The machine to be used for the job should be configured as an Azure DevOps self-hosted agent (see [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)).

From the information that you shared, your pipeline was running on Microsoft-hosted `windows-latest` agent.

Please follow the guidance in [Continuous integration with Azure DevOps (microfocus.com)](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2023-2023-r1/help/WebHelp/Content/Controller/Azure_DevOps.htm) to setup proper environment and configure you pipeline to run on that agent machine.

Comment: Thanks Alvin for your reply. Yes, I am trying on windows-latest i.e Microsoft hosted agent, cant we do it on the Microsoft hosted agent. Currently, we don't have Microsoft self hosted agent. can we do it on Linux self hosted agent ? thanks Again

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Good day and thanks for the update. I don't think it is possible to run this task on MS-hosted agent at moment, as the LoadRuner is not installed on MS-hosted agents. (See [softerware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software)). Even using a Windows self-hosted agent machine to run this task, it requires LoadRunner Professional to be installed as a prerequisite.

Comment: Meanwhile, since LoadRunner is the author and maintainer of this extension task, you may reach out to LoadRunner support to check if they have a plan to develop a new task for their software installation in order to run the current task on MS-hosted agents and get more insights.

Comment: Thanks Alvin for your reply. I have tried with self hosted agent i am getting  "##[error]Unhandled: spawn powershell.exe ENOENT" error is this related to access to run powershell?  thanks Again.

Comment: May I know if you could run `powershell` pipeline task using this self-hosted agent pool? If not, may I know if any of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750620/how-to-fix-error-spawnsync-powershell-exe-enoent and https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/issues/150 can resolve this issue? Please restart your agent service or reboot the Windows agent machine after you update the environment variables.